# Getting Error when importing pyparsing in ubuntu?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04

Getting following error

```
>>> from pyparsing import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pyparsing.py", line 9, in <module>
    pp.Literal("+") |
NameError: name 'pp' is not defined
```

Install python version 2.7.6 and ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I suspect you created your own file called `pyparsing.py`, and you're importing that instead of the real `pyparsing` library.  Name your file something else.

Comment: Oh..yes..I am the one of the stupidest person alive....thanks a lot